# When internet connection is not available on Android App, not show AdMob

Tags: android, admob

I want to listen to internet access on Android App,if not available internet hide AdMob Area. By the way my application context are will be wider.
If there is internet access, i want to show AdMob and Area.
How can I do it?
thanks

Answer (score 3):

That already is the default behaviour of AdMob. You don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Register the following as a BroadcastReceiver to find out when the internet connection changes. When you have connection you can display the AdView.

```
private BroadcastReceiver wifiConnectionListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        final boolean isOnline = (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());

        Log.d(TAG, "#onReceive wifiNetworkInfo=" + networkInfo);
        Log.d(TAG, "#onReceive online=" + isOnline + " isConnected=" + getMessageSender().isConnected());

        if (isOnline) {
            Log.d(TAG, "#onReceive showing AdView");
            // TODO Show your AdView
        }
    }
};
```

And then register the BroadcastListsner

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(wifiConnectionListener, 
      new IntentFilter(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
```

Comment: You forgot the Intent Filter.

Comment: You don't need an IntentFilter when you define the BroadcastReceiver programatically.

Comment: You still have to register the BroadcastReceiver *for* an IntentFilter.